# Cannot upgrade/Install plugins on Eclipse for OS X

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I was trying to install the PyDev plugin for Eclipse on OS X and I realized I cannot access the "Find and Install" option. When I go to Help > Software Update both the "Find and Install" and "Manage Configuration" are grayed out.

Since I am running Eclipse 3.6.0 I thought an upgrade to 3.7 might fix it, but I would need to access that menu in order to upgrade wouldn't I?

Does anyone know of a fix?

Eclipse 3.6.0
OS X 10.7.3

**Update: Issue resolved by a fresh upgrade to Eclipse 3.7**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it's disabled in your case, but anyways, when upgrading to a newer version of Eclipse, don't use the update menu, always grab a new version from Eclipse.org and reinstall the plugins you use (i.e.: to get Eclipse 3.7) -- note: just point to the same workspace you had previously after you update all the plugins you use (point to a different workspace while you're updating the plugins so that you don't mess with your current workspace because features are not available until you install all plugins).

As for updating PyDev, usually go to the 'Install new software', add the PyDev update site (see links at: http://pydev.org/download.html) and go from there -- if it's grayed out, grab a new Eclipse and go from there :)

Comment: Thank you @Fabio I ended doing just that. I installed a fresh version of 3.7 and now I am able to add plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what menu options you're referring to. You should select the Help menu and then select the Install New Software option directly under Help. You shouldn't do anything involving software updates, as installing PyDev is done as if it's new software, so I think you're going wrong when you select the Software Update option.

Even though they are a little outdated in terms of Eclipse, I was able to install in Mac OS X with Eclipse 3.6 using [these instructions](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/resources/Eclipse/eclipse-python-configuration.htm).

Comment: The thing is I had no Install New Software option when I was running 3.6.0. I resolved the issue by installing 3.7 and am currently running PyDev. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem, but you should try to check on what was going wrong. I am running Eclipse 3.6 right now on Mac OS X 10.7.3 and there definitely is an 'Install New Software' option directly under the Help menu. I can't imagine any kind of one-off error that would *completely remove* a whole menu from Eclipse, so there might be a serious problem there that's not safe to ignore just because of the new working version.